# Divide data on the regional basis

Tags: territory-management

It would be great if any help on how to implement the business requirement below..

We are having teams across regions, data on custom objects belonging to a region should not be accessible between regions.

Users in a region have their own role hierarchy and record level access should roll up via this hirearchy

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us if you've already tried something based on the implementation guide http://eu3.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_territories_implementation_guide.pdf   or general help  http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_def.htm ?  Knowing what you've already done, and where you're stuck will help us answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to answer my own question...

OWD settings on Custom object to Private.

Set up Role for each manager with his sub-ordinates reporting to him and all the regional manager reporting to VP......